# Interceptor on a class method belonging to External Dependency

Tags: quarkus

We have an Aspect in our code that had been PointCut on Hibernate class.

Our Aspect class looks something like this:

```
@PointCut("(execution(* *.getQueryString(..))" + "|| execution(* *.getQuery(..)))" + "&& (target(org.hibernate.engine.NamedSQLQueryDefinition))")
public void aroundNamedSQLQueryDefinitionGetQuery() {
}

@Around("aroundNamedSQLQueryDefinitionGetQuery")
public String addExtraFilter(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Exception {
    //Logic to add extra filter to the Query.
}
```

Now we are trying to migrate this code to Quarkus. We have replaced Aspects with Interceptors which were present on code belonging to our modules.

But how do we add Interceptors on Hibernate classes?
Is there an alternate way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

A [Quarkus extension](https://quarkus.io/guides/writing-extensions) would allow you to manipulate the Hibernate classes (or your own classes).

To scaffold a basic extension,

```
mvn io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.10.1.Final:create-extension -N \
    -DgroupId=org.you \ 
    -DextensionId=aspectorama
```

Then, in the `[whatever]Processor` class that gets created, you could add an [`AnnotationTransformerBuildItem`](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/main/extensions/arc/deployment/src/main/java/io/quarkus/arc/deployment/AnnotationsTransformerBuildItem.java)

```
    @BuildStep
    AnnotationsTransformerBuildItem transform() {
        return new AnnotationsTransformerBuildItem(new AnnotationsTransformer() {

            public boolean appliesTo(org.jboss.jandex.AnnotationTarget.Kind kind) {
                return kind == org.jboss.jandex.AnnotationTarget.Kind.METHOD;
            }

            public void transform(TransformationContext context) {
              if ("org.hibernate.engine.NamedSQLQueryDefinition".equals(context.getTarget().asMethod().declaringClass().name()) && ("getQueryString").equals(context.getTarget().asMethod().name()) {
                    context.transform().add(YourAnnotation.class).done();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

(I haven't tested that, and I may not have quite the method names you intended. I only did `getQueryString` not `getQuery`... but it shows the idea.)

You may also need to tell Quarkus about your interceptor if it's not in the main application codebase:

```
   /**
     * Makes the interceptor as a bean so we can access it.
     */
    @BuildStep
    void beans(BuildProducer<AdditionalBeanBuildItem> producer) {
        producer.produce(AdditionalBeanBuildItem.unremovableOf(YourInterceptor.class));
        producer.produce(AdditionalBeanBuildItem.unremovableOf(OtherExtraBean.class));
    }
```

It may be that the annotation route isn't the best for your use case, and you could make the changes you needed more directly. It's worth browsing [all the Quarkus build items](https://quarkus.io/guides/all-builditems), which are kind of like a library of built-in extension capabilities. For example, you can use `@Record` to [create bytecode](https://quarkus.io/guides/writing-extensions#bytecode-recording).

Comment: Using an extension to add an interceptor to a pre-existing class is sound, but note that interceptors only apply to CDI beans. I'm not totally exactly 1000% sure, but I believe `NamedSQLQueryDefinition` is not a bean, so that won't work.

Comment: Holly Cummins, I tried with your approach, but it did not work. As @Ladicek suggested since it is not a Bean it did not get invoked. I will try your other suggestion of using Record to create bytecode.